# Cannot get 1px to line up with main border

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

How can the css markup below be modified such that the added extra 1 pixel the active clicked on tab to disappear and be removed from my UL LI Tabbed Menu as seen below?

Here is pic of the problem:
[image]

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="container">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Tab 1 Content</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Tab 2 Content</div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Tab 3 Content</div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">Tab 4 Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {width: 500px; margin: 10px auto;}
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 31px;

}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}   
html ul.tabs li.active {
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(230,139,44);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #fff;

}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.tab_content h3 a{
    color: #254588;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/apamvz1r/3/

Works fine here.

Comment: What browser are you viewing this in?

Comment: ...and at what zoom level?

Comment: When you set an Height, if you add a boder, that height will increment that X pixels from top and/or bottom, if you don't use box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines (added at the bottom) fixed it:

```
ul.tabs { 
    border-bottom: none;
}
/* Why are you using `html` here? No point to it! */
html ul.tabs li.active {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

You don't need a full border below your tabs to draw the lines, let your `li` elements take care of that, and then just shift the `1px` border from the bottom to the top by adding it to the `border-top`. When not using `box-sizing: border-box` you have to make sure that your borders all add up to the same amount to prevent things like this from happening.

```css
.container {width: 500px; margin: 10px auto;}
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 31px;

}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}   
html ul.tabs li.active {
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(230,139,44);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #fff;

}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.tab_content h3 a{
    color: #254588;
}

ul.tabs { border-bottom: none; }
html ul.tabs li.active { border-bottom: none; }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Tab 1 Content</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Tab 2 Content</div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Tab 3 Content</div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">Tab 4 Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shift the content up a pixel:

```
html ul.tabs li.active a {
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7adfsmdj/

Answer (score 0):

change the height as 30px in *ul.tabs*
since you gave as 30px in *ul.tabs li*

---

```
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: **30px;**

}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: **30px;**
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}
```

Comment: I think it needs to be 29px, because of the added 2px top border for active state.